# Integrating the sign function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, solution-verification

Let $sgn(t)=1$ when $t>0$, $sgn(t)=0 $ when $t=0$, and $sgn(t)=-1$ when $t<0$.

Show that $$S(x):=\int_{-1}^{x}sgn(t)dt$$ is equal to $|x|-1$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$

**My attempt:**
If $x=-1$, then

$S(-1)=\int_{-1}^{-1}sgn(t)dt=0=|-1|-1=|x|-1.$

---

If $x=0$, then

$S(0)=\int_{-1}^{0}sgn(t)dt=\int_{-1}^{0}-1\cdot dt=-\int_{-1}^{0}1\cdot dt=-1(0--1)=-1=|x|-1$

---

If $x=1$ then

$S(1)=\int_{-1}^{1}sgn(t)dt=\int_{-1}^{0}sgn(t)dt+\int_{0}^{1}sgn(t)dt=-1+\int_{0}^{1}1\cdot dt=-1+(1-0)=0=|x|-1$.

---

If $x\in(-1,0)$

$S(x)=\int_{-1}^{x}sgn(t)dt=\int_{-1}^{x}-1\cdot dt=-\int_{-1}^{x}1\cdot dt=-1(x--1)=-x-1$

---

If $x\in(0,1)$ then

$S(x)=\int_{-1}^{x}sgn(t)dt=\int_{-1}^{0}sgn(t)dt+\int_{0}^{x}sgn(t)dt=-1+\int_{0}^{x}1\cdot dt=-1+(x-0)=-1+x$.

---

Is my solution correct? Does it show what I was asked to prove? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct, but you could have saved a lot of work by showing that $|x|'=\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ (with an arbitrary choice for $x=0$, which doesn't matter since isolated discontinuities can be ignored in integration) and then applying the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by "an arbitrary choice for $x=0$?

Comment: @user926356 $|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$, and other motivated choices exist for the sign function at $0$ (e.g. $1$ and $-1$). Since that is just one point, however, integration need not care about it.

Comment: So you're saying the value assigned to the function at 0 doesn't really matter, right?

Comment: @user926356 Yes.